# Numeric field Simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my numeric fields when using Simple_form_for, scroll bars are showed on the side of the fields when using Google Chrome.

How can I stop them from showing?

[image: Image showing numeric fields with Scroll Simple_form_for]

Answer (score 16):

**Seeing some code would be helpful**, but

They're not scrollbars; they're up and down arrow buttons to increment/decrement the `number` input field the specified `step` (defaults to `1`). **[Learn more about the `number` input type](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php)**

An integer attribute for your model by default will be rendered with `type="number"` as a field using [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

To override this behavior, specify the type of input for the field using the `:as` option.

```
<%= f.input :your_field_name, as: :string %>
```

(This is documented in the **[`README.md`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md)**)

Comment: I am wondering, if i use the as: :string , won't it input my integer values as strings?

Comment: Regardless of the submission method of the form (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE), in `params` rails is still going to show `:your_field_name`'s value as a string. You *always* must cast it with something like `to_i` if you want it as an integer.

Comment: Thanks Bro,You gave me exactly what i want. :)

Comment: How can i add + and - to right and left, instead of scroll?