# simple_form / bootstrap number field arrows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Can anyone help me get rid of the arrows in these fields?

[image: these arrows]

I'm using rails, simple_form and bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: This has been asked before and answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709950/numeric-field-simple-form-for

Comment: Thankyou trh, I had implemented that method but this allows users to type non-numeric values into the field. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaah, you're a chrome user most likely :), ya, you can hide them with a css override.

```
form input[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
form input[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: How can i add + and - to right and left, instead of scroll?